# installing libraries for linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, libraries

I have just installed a linux virtual machine on my windows. I am completely new to linux so I would like to ask how to add these libraries to my ubuntu linux.

- g++ - the version 4.4
- graphviz
- gnuplot
- plotdrop
- libboost version 1.38
- libgsl0-dbg
- libgsl0-dev
- libgsl0ldbl

Then how to run the "make" command :)

Thank you ;)
Sorry I ask a beginner question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Linux?

Most...arm, all disitrbutions have their own software repositories, check the doumentation of each out to find out from where you can install new software.

For Ubuntu, have a look at Synaptic, it will hold allof these packages you wanna install.

Comment: Ohh, thank Bobby. The Synaptic package manager is the right one to install all of them ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install g++ graphviz gnuplot gnuplot plotdrop libboost1.38-dev libgsl0-dbg libgsl0-dev libgsl0ldbl
```

To run make, type `make`.